# É possível discriminar valores desestruturados de um objeto com tipo de união em TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Percebi que, ao realizar a desestruturação na assinatura da função (`funcao({ a, b }: Objeto)`), acabo perdendo uma certa consistência dos tipos. No caso específico em que percebi isso, sempre apenas uma das propriedades está definida (`a` ou `b`), mas ao realizar a desestruturação, o TypeScript "esquece" isso.

Por exemplo:

```js
type CatsOrDogs =
  | { cats: string[]; dogs?: undefined }
  | { cats?: undefined; dogs: string[] };

// Funciona
function test(obj: CatsOrDogs) {
  if (obj.cats !== undefined) {
    obj.cats.push('');
  } else {
    obj.dogs.push('');
  }
}

// Não funciona
function testDestructuring({ cats, dogs }: CatsOrDogs) {
  if (cats !== undefined) {
    cats.push('');
  } else {
    dogs.push(''); // Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)
  }
}
```

<sup>Veja no [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsAzgeQE4BED2BzRUC8AUFFAD5QDeUAxgogFxSLCoCWAdtgNoC6A3FAAmORAH5GAV3aCIAMw4RBUAL7EylGnXFQpM%20e0UDhuRszadeKvoUKyp1YK0zsowCMwAUmAEYArRvBIaFi4AJSUaqyyUF5%20AHS0SFAAhPj4OtJyCoLhFGokPr4JdHFgEogAFh4A5NWh1iTKUBAANojQeSQF8caIpeVVtfVqqqq29o7Oru7A6DOoEg4S5tgeVImIADRCIioBdMEiuZHRHhspaRl62cddmkj9lTV1DSrNbR35O7iPgy9QAHoAVBkH4IA4oKw8GBMIhEKxvC0QFBqrosgZBNU4h4AEwAVgAzDjQiNCMogA).</sup>

- Como posso fazer para criar esse tipo `CatsOrDogs` sem perder a consistência na desestruturação?
- Ou então, existe outra maneira de ter o comportamento desejado sem abrir mão do uso da desestruturação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Atualização (28/02/2022)

A partir da versão 4.6 do TypeScript, publicada no dia 28 de fevereiro de 2022, o sistema de tipos da linguagem permite expressar o tipo de código tratado na pergunta.

Ver, nas notas de edição, a seção [“Control Flow Analysis for Destructured Discriminated Unions”](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions).

Ver o código original funcionando no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsAzgeQE4BED2BzRUC8AUFFAD5QDeUAxgogFxSLCoCWAdtgNoC6A3FAAmORAH5GAV3aCIAMw4RBUAL7EylGnXFQpM+e0UDhuRszadeKvoUIB6W1ABiU6q0zs4hWS+Bv2UYAhmAApMACMAK0Z4JDQsXABKSjVWWShQyIA6WiQoAEJ8fB1pOQVBJIo1EnCI7LpMsAlEAAtggHI2hOsSZSgIABtEaEqSaqzjRAam1o6utVVVOwcAOQBjzChvdld3Ty3qX3cAoOB0E9QJA4lzbGCqHMQAGiERFWi6OJEKlLTgh-zCsU9GVvqNNEgpi12p1uio+oNhlUwciUVB7FAAKLMaAQVCoDbsdZQTDUTB46AAWzgrEmSImkJmMLRDmQkQgBygNKgYEwiEQrDC-RAUDaulKBkEbUywQATABWADMMoS80IyiAA).

---

#### Resposta antiga

Em muito resumo, não é possível fazer a desestruturação antes do *branching* e ainda realizar a discriminação dos tipos da união.

Repare que, quando você faz a desestruturação antes do *branching* (nesse caso pelo `if`), o compilador não tem como definir o tipo do valor desestruturado mediante o local em que for usado. Por conta disso, o tipo inferido para esse valor será o mais genérico possível. No caso de uniões, o tipo será a união de todas as variantes correspondentes à propriedade em questão.

Então:

```
type CatsOrDogs =
  | { cats: string[]; dogs?: undefined }
  | { cats?: undefined; dogs: string[] };

const catsOrDogs: CatsOrDogs = {} as any; // Ignore isso, só para demonstrar o valor.

const { cats } = catsOrDogs;
// Tipo de `cats` será `string[] | undefined`.
```

Nesse exemplo, não é factível esperar que o compilador associe ao tipo da variável `cats` as condições em que ele possa ser `string[]` ou `undefined`. Portanto, o tipo inferido será `string[] | undefined`.

Você pode, no entanto, realizar a desestruturação uma vez que o *branching* já tenha sido realizado:

```
type CatsOrDogs =
  | { cats: string[]; dogs?: undefined }
  | { cats?: undefined; dogs: string[] };

const catsOrDogs: CatsOrDogs = {} as any; // Ignore isso, só para demonstrar o valor.

if (catsOrDogs.cats) {
  const { cats } = catsOrDogs;
  // Dentro deste branch, o tipo de `cats` será `string[]`.
}
```

É importante ter em mente que, em uniões, a informação necessária para que o compilador faça a discriminação encontra-se no objeto inteiro (que possui o *union type*). Uma vez que você desestruture um objeto antes que o compilador tenha feito a discriminação, os valores desestruturados não terão qualquer habilidade para a realizar.

Comment: Curiosamente eu fiz uma [pergunta sobre isso no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61419196/7445826) há um tempo. :v

Answer (score -2):

Tente isso:

```
function testDestructuring({ cats, dogs }: CatsOrDogs) {
  cats?.push('')
  dogs?.push('');
}
```

A inferência de tipos funciona, podes ver isso ao passar o mouse em cima de `cats` ou `dogs` dentro da `function`. Lá está descrito qual será o tipo da váriavel. No seu caso cats pode ser tanto um array quanto pode ser undefined. O mesmo serve para o dogs.

Comment: Veja o exemplo `test`. Eu tenho certeza que ou `cats` ou `dogs` é um array, e o outro é `undefined`. O problema ao fazer a desestruturação é que preciso usar o *optional chaining* `?.` no `else` do meu exemplo `testDestructuring`. O que quero é justamente não usar o `?.`, já que sei que não será undefined.